# Scrapy Mysql insert error

Tags: python, mysql, scrapy

I am trying to save in MySQL scrapped items with Scrapy, my code was running like a charm with scrapy 0.24 although in 1.0.1 i have mysql errors that i can not understand where they come from.

Part of my Pipeline:

```
def process_item(self, item, spider):    
    if item['date'] != "":
        try:
            sql = ("INSERT INTO "+item['tablename']+" VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)")
            self.cursor.execute(sql, 
                (
                item['id'],                 
                item['title'], 
                item['link'],
                item['body'],
                item['date'],               
                json.dumps(item['images'])                  
                ))
            self.conn.commit()
        except MySQLdb.Error, e:
            print "************** Error ************"               
            print "Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0], e.args[1])
            print "************** End ************"
    return item
```

Sample values of my inserts:

```
 id : 234264953566255283759266697433875136366452113806L
 date : 'September 10, 2014'
 images : {'checksum': '839ea50f9275a821975e0b70ca8838df',
         'path': 'full/4b1fc7128e958c47b451936d6b5636b6ddfd2b14.jpg',
         'url': 'http://content.domain.com/origin/Spaces/Production/Cms/POLL/n64wjrlnh0ayoe2gxo26-q.png'}
 link : 'http://www.example.com/178400/xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxx-xx.aspx'
 body : '<div class="articlecontent" itemprop="articleBody"> \r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n <p>lorem ipsums</p>\r\n<p style="text-align:center">'
 title : 'German Leadership Vies With U.S. in Global Popularity'
```

And the outpout error:

```
  ************** Error ************
  Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
  corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
  '),   'http://www.example.com/178400/xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxx-xx.aspx' at  line 1
   ************** End ************
```

By printing the query in terminal the way its going to be executed i get:

```
   INSERT INTO tablename VALUES      (1245845410931227995499360226027473197403882391305, 
  ("\'lorem Ipsum\'",), 
  'http://www.example.com/178400/xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxx-xx.aspx', 
  (), 
  (), 
  '[]')",
```

I think extras commas ',' has been added although i don't know why or how to fix it. Any help appreciated, if needed, i can provide any additional info.

****** EDIT ******

After i changed the %s into the values from "%s" to "?" i get a different error

```
   TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

   on the line : json.dumps(item['images'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem solved by casting the

```
   json.dumps(item['images'])
```

to a string like this:

```
   str(json.dumps(item['images']))
```

I don't really know if this the best way or even why that was needed since it was not necessary in version 0.24 but it works now, the data are inserted in my DB normally.